# How to join with aggregate arrays on value in jsonb array in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

```
Games
+----------------+--------+-------+------+
|     Title      | GameId | Genre | Tag |
+----------------+--------+-------+------+
| Aeon           | A1     | RPG   | B1   |
| Questerra      | A2     | RPG   | B2   |
| Age of Thunder | A3     | RPG   | B3   |
+----------------+--------+-------+------+
```

```
Items
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|   Type    |                            Objects                             |
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Longsword | {type: 'weapon', game_ids: ['A1', 'A3'], tag_ids: ['B1']}      |
| Scimitar  | {type: 'weapon', game_ids: ['A2'], tag_ids: ['B2', 'B3']}      |
| Longbow   | {type: 'weapon': game_ids: ['A1', 'A2'], tag_ids: ['B2', 'B3'} |
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have tables similar to the above.  Columns `GameIds` and `TagIds` are both `jsonb` types that contain arrays `ids`.  What I would like to do is return an array of `Type` along with table `Games` where either a `GameId` or `Tag` is in `Objects.game_ids` or `Objects.tag_ids` respectively.  I sort of have an idea of how this is supposted to work.  I think it's something like

```sql
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(it.Type) Types, g.*
FROM Games as g
LEFT JOIN Items as it
ON TRUE
WHERE (
  it.Objects::jsonb #> '{game_ids}' ? g.GameId::text
  OR
  it.Objects::jsonb #> '{tag_ids}' ? g.Tag::text
);
```

but this query executes and never resolves.  There's no indication of an error, and I suspect that it's either not doing what I expect it to or is just insanely inefficient.  What should this query look like?

Comment: It is slow because you are joining large tables with a nested loop join. At fault is your terrible data model: normalize it and avoid storing foreign keys in arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery with `array_to_json`:

```
select g.*, (select array_to_json(array_agg(i.type)) 
             from items i
             where exists (select 1 from jsonb_array_elements(i.objects -> 'game_ids') v where v.value::text = concat('"', g.gameid, '"'))
             or exists (select 1 from jsonb_array_elements(i.objects -> 'tag_ids') v where v.value::text = concat('"', g.tag, '"')))
from games g;
```